# Why is an emf induced in a coil when it is not moving perpendicular to magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I am a 10th grade student, and while reading my book, I came across the figure below that illustrates the change of magnetic flux through a coil. The motion of the coil is not perpendicular to the magnetic field, then how is an emf induced in the coil that causes current to flow and thereby deflecting the centre- zero galvanometer? Is my book wrong or have I misunderstood it? 
[image: Magnetic Flux through a Coil]

Answer (score 1):

If the magnetic field were uniform you'd be quite correct in saying that no EMF is induced. However the magnetic field is not uniform. The field becomes stronger the closer you get to the magnet, so the flux through the coil increases as you move the coil closer to the magnet. It is this increase in the flux with time that causes the EMF.

Comment: Would you please tell me then how can I use Flemming's right hand rule in this case?

Comment: @SuyashIshan Flemming's right hand rule is used in electric generators for finding the direction of current from two given perpendicular directions of motion and magnetic field. This rule is not useful in this particular case as it's strictly designed to be used when the directions are perpendicular to each other, you'll be better off applying Lenz law and then finding direction of current corresponding to the opposing magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic flux is given by:
$$\Phi=B A\cos\theta$$
where $B$ is the magnitude of magnetic field, $A$ is the area of the coil that is penetrated by $B$ and $\theta$ is the angle between them.

So for flux to change there can be a change **any** of the three: $B$, $A$ or $\theta$.

1. When you’re moving the coil perpendicular to $B$, $A$ is changing.
2. When you’re rotating the coil (as happens in motors/generators), $\theta$ is changing.
3. In the example given in your question, $B$ is changing.